Do most philosophies boil things down to polarities (opposites), or no?
A lot of philosophies boil things down to polarities. For example:

Yin/yang in ancient Chinese philosophy.
Dualities in the Kybalion "Everything is dual; everything has poles; everything has its pair of opposites; like and unlike are the same; opposites are identical in nature, but different in degree; extremes meet; all truths are but half-truths; all paradoxes may be reconciled."
Etc..

I have thought a little about this and it appears that there are not just polarities, but at least 3 classes of property values:

On-off values (not opposites, but a single property like "itchy" or "spikey", which can have "more" or "less" of an intensity. There is no opposite to itchy or spikey. At least the way I look at things. If you say "non-itchy" as an opposite, what does that even mean? Basically it boils down to "no value" or "some value", of one property.
Opposite values. These are your typical "polarities" like hot/cold, bright/dim, heavy/light, etc.. Each is a single property with a pair of values on a spectrum, ranging from one side to the other.
Multidimensional values. These are things like "color", which has at least red/blue/green (rgb, 3 values ranging from 0-255 on modern computers), or hue/saturation/lightness (hsl). I think most "properties" belong to this category TBH, but I can't think of many more. In coding, these are "data models" or "types with attributes".

So the main pressing question on my mind is, am I wrong, and in fact everything can be boiled down to polarities somehow? Or are there philosophies which take it the direction more along the lines of what I'm doing (with at least these 3 categories)? What is the spectrum of philosophy here?
If everything can be boiled down to polarities, please explain in some depth, using my examples from (1) and (3) to demonstrate how those can be seen as part of a polarity spectrum.

Almost no philosophies boil things down to polarities.

Virtues, in Greek, are often seen as polarities. @DavidGudeman can you provide examples where that is the case, in a full answer?

It is clearly nonsense to imagine that everything can be boiled down to polarities. Please explain how the New Forest, for example, can be boiled down to a polarity.

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a faulty premise.

Consider looking in to Nonduality.

You might like this answer on how 'opposites' arw bit simply things found in the world, but cobstructesby us through language-games of analogy & metaphor: 'Life and Death as one and the same?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/98365/life-and-death-as-one-and-the-same/98369#98369 Modern science largely regards everything as coming from one point in time & space, the Big Bang, & so arising from a fundamental unity. You might wish to investigate 'wuji' (preexisting unity) in contrast to 'taiji' (the Yin-Yang is just 1 example of), even Taoism doesn't make polarity fundamental..!

@MarcoOcram: New vs old, forest vs field, woods vs trees, living vs petrified, hexagram 19 (wood over earth), cats can't have any forest vs cats can have a little forest as a treet ;)

I get it, faulty premise. But what do I know. I'm over here in the dark on my computer trying to write code to boil things down into clear categories, and I realized polarities are not universal, after being immersed in Taoism and just finishing a Kybalion reading. I have been reading Jewish/Islam/Christian texts as well, but I wasn't sure it was there or not, but then Plato's virtues are divided into opposites (and Christianity uses those). So I guess I made a mistake in assuming it was a common perspective! Forgot about non-duality in Sanskrit. Completely overlooked "mono-theism" haha.

It is easy to see whatever you are looking for.

@ScottRowe I am not looking for polarities. But what you are saying resonates as well, as my mind is like a slide rule, as I move along I forget what I knew before, and my window of what I can recall is only so big. So sometimes I get lodged into holes which I can't see clearly out of for a little while, forgetting what I once knew. I feel like that must happen to lots of people.

Non-duality —  advaita in sanskrit — is the exact answer to your question.
a-dvai-ta literally means «not-two-ness»
the very word itself is a negation of polarities.  The natural positive equivalent would be monism — Oneness. But that immediately makes bubble up twoness, threeness manyness. It was a deep insight of the original non-dual rishis that non-duality can be expressed only indirectly, often by negation.
I won't say much more about it but rather expand on how and why
we find ourselves hopelessly stuck in a twoness/divided world. There are (IMHO) 3
principle addictions:
Addictions

Language
Education
Body orientation

1. Language
Language is predicative ie boolean whereas reality is continuous; language is linear, reality is multi dimensional1.
2. Education
Our education from as early as we can remember is twoness oriented:

like dislike
good bad
true false

The great Buddhist philosopher Nagarjuna threw a heavy duty spanner into the works. I recommend it if only for the chuckles.
3. The body idea
Ramana Maharshi, widely regarded as the greatest advaita teacher of the 20th century, summed up his entire teaching as:

You must get rid of the »I-am-the-body« idea

What does this have to do with twoness and it's negation??
From the moment of our birth we're taught to distinguish what's on this side of "my" skin and the other — me vs not-me.
From this arises fear-pain-ego-hell.
Clearly we need some basic reflexes to be programmed into us early to not put for example knives in our mouth, hands in a fire etc, etc.
But (IMHO) we use this a hundredfold more than we need to putting the whole world in a violent convulsion against itself.
Example
Nonduality is better learnt from living practitioners than from philosophers.
I suggest Gandhi:

I do not believe...that an individual may gain spiritually and those who
surround him suffer. I believe in advaita, I believe in the essential unity of man
and, for that matter, of all that lives. Therefore, I believe that if one man
gains spiritually, the whole world gains with him and, if one man falls, the
whole world falls to that extent.
I do not believe that the spiritual law works on a field of its own. On the
contrary, it expresses itself only through the ordinary activities of life. It thus
affects the economic, the social and the political fields.
Mind of Mahatma Gandhi

Gandhi didn't say those English are bad we Indians are good.
Instead he said (in effect) : We won't fight you, you do what you have to do2.
This act of lowering the ego self defense reflex was something the world's greatest superpower was powerless and helpless to counter.

1 See the separation into two — world vs language? It's clever. It's a lie — language is not ‘extra terrestrial’!
2 Well literally he does say we must fight but it's not to fight in any way that would generally be recognized as such.

You may be looking for trilemmas or otherwise multi-polar mutually exclusives. Each option, if turned On, turns the other two or more options Off.

Of a claim: true, false, category error.

Of a path to the other side of a barrier: over, around, or through.


You can have a similar structure with an option for more/less instead of on/off, where each option, if turned More, turns the other two or more options Less.

Of a displacement from the center of a regular tetrahedron: towards
any of four vertices (thus away from the other three).

Of a potato: more ready for planting, more tasty, more rotten.


It would be a very strange philosophy which didn't allow for sets of more than two mutually exclusive or mutually diminishing elements.

Right, but as a first approximation you can divide in two, then divide the two piles in to two and so on. We can't defeat boolean reasoning, but we don't have to worship it either. (See how there are two options there, and I said no to both?)
